# How make diff command skip identic or formatted lines

Tags: linux, diff

I need a simple quick aswer how to refine the following command:

```
diff -rupN folder1 folder2 > mydiff.diff
```

so that the result file will only reflect real changes not formatted or logical identic lines.

Comment: Have you consulted the man page for diff?

Answer (score 1):

`diff` has a `-w` flag to ignore whitespace in comparisons.  That should be what you're looking for.
In addition, some versions of `diff` support `-B` to ignore blank lines.

Check the `man diff` or `diff --help` for more info.

Comment: Yes that seems to be an improvement. Thanks